# Bytes addressable processor

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, mips

In MIPS processor, address bus is of 32 bits. So on addressing an instruction, a whole 32 bit instruction is fetched. How is it byte addressable then? I mean if on addressing a particular address, the memory sends 32 bits as a wholesome, how is it byte addressable?

Comment: I guess you are mixing the concepts a bit here. I would suggest you to learn more about the concept and gain the much needed conceptual clarity. try the resources mentioned below https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/09au/lectures/cse378au09-02.pdf If you still have any doubts then you can let me know. Much happy to help :) .

Comment: Address bus is for addresses, data bus is for data. 32 bit address bus doesn't tell you anything about the amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

"Byte addressable" means that a 32-bit address points to a single byte of memory, so if you increment that address, it points one byte further.

"Word addressable" means that (on a 32-bit processor) every 32-bit address points to a 32-bit word, so if you increment that address, it points *four* bytes further in memory.

Some machines can support both byte addressable and word addressable modes of operation.  But for the naming, we're concerned with the *smallest* unit they can address.

Comment: Just to complete the answer, the fact that the memory is byte-addressable (each address = 1byte) doesn't mean you can't reference a word in the memory. That is, if you tell the processor to work with words, it will reference the word (4bytes) that lies in addresses (addr, addr+1, addr+2,addr+3)  assuming addr=0 mod 4.